# Installing imutils in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm unable to install [imutils](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) using commandline in ubuntu. I've used "pip install imutils" but its showing an error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_amorthyo/imutils/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Beko63-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_amorthyo/imutils
Storing debug log for failure in /home/amorthyo/.pip/pip.log
```

Please can anyone help????

Comment: Like the error says, the installer cannot create a file because permission is denied. You probably need to run the installer as root, e.g. by using `sudo pip install imutils`.

Answer (score 8):

Your user doesn't have permission to write to that location.  **You need not run pip as root**.

Try this instead:

```
pip install --user imutils
```

And add your local site packages directory to the PYTHONPATH - since you said you're on Ubuntu, this is likely at `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.  Other readers should check the output of `python -m site` to find the user site directory and see if it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: 
 `sudo pip install imutils`
It might be an issue of permission denied.